# MySQL field type to count bytes filesize

Tags: php, mysql, count, filesize

I'm storing document information (Word, excel, ...) in a MySQL database.
I have a column "size" where I store the filesize in bytes like 582656, 136260, 383266...
But when I order by size, the results are a little bit disorderly. What type of MySQL field should I use?
I've tried VARCHAR and INT, the same result.

Comment: Please could you post your table structure and the query that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VARCHAR will definitely give you the incorrect results as is will sort from left to right.

> eg, VARCHAR sorted will place 12
>   before 2, as the first 1 in 12 is less
>   than 2.

But INT should give you what you require.

Have a look at a couple of types here

[Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

Comment: Your are right. It's works. I'm using a view to display my data and forget to change the colum type in the view...

Thanks !